# Windows Vista boot screen customization

Tags: windows-7, boot, windows-vista

I have a Windows 7 computer with the old ugly Windows Vista boot screen. Because it's an netbook, it has a small screen so it doesn't support the new lovely Windows 7 boot screen animation. Is there any way I could replace the old Windows Vista boot screen with an image or with the new Windows 7 animation?

Remember, I don't mean login screen, I mean boot logo.

Answer (score 0):

the new Windows 7 boot logo only work with a resolution of at least 1024 * 768 pixels. You can try the [old Vista Boot logo hacks](http://www.tacktech.com/display.cfm?ttid=389) and see if they also work for Win7.